# Access Swift's Optional Type in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a hybrid (Swift/Objective C) iOS Project.   Here's the Swift code snippet in my iOS app:

```
let envPlist = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("environment", ofType: "plist")
let envDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: envPlist!)

class BuildEnv: NSObject {
    internal class func envKey() -> String? {
        return envDict["envKey"]?.string
    }
}
```

When I print envKey in Objective C in log:

```
NSLog(@"BUILDENV ENV = %@", [BuildEnv envKey]);
```

I got:

```
BUILDENV ENV = (null)
```

But if I changed the Swift func to:

```
internal class func envKey() -> String {
    return envDict["envKey"] as String!
}
```

Then I was able to print the value in Objective C.  Does anyone know how to handle this elegantly?

Comment: You seem to be calling a `string` property in the value returned from your `NSDictionary`, here: `envDict["envKey"]?.string`, but not later: `envDict["envKey"] as String!`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using `["envKey"]?.string` .You should not use `["envKey"]?` it will not unwrap `AnyObject?`.

```
    return envDict["envKey"]?.string  //notice ?
```

instead you should optional cast `AnyObject` to `String`

```
    return envDict["envKey"] as? String
```

`as?` returns optional `String?`